# How to import file in parallel directory?

Tags: python, import

My project's structure is the following:

```
                                       - test.py
                                       /
                            - test(dir) 
                           /
                          /
proj(dir) ---- src(dir)           
               - __init__.py   
                          \
                           \
                            - encryption(dir) 
                                             \
                                              - __init__.py
                                              - encrypt.py
```

In `test.py`, I'm trying to import `ecrypt.py` as such:

```py
from src.encryption import encrypt
```

But, when trying to run `test.py`, I get the following output:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.encryption import encrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.2
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `src` to you path.

Before you run `from src.encryption import encrypt`, maybe try running the following codes:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(['/path/to/your/src'])
```

This works for me.

Comment: It doesn't for me :(

Comment: `sys.path.extend(['../../'])` worked. (`../../` being my root directory)